Zabbix monitoring JSON-File
I want to monitor a JSON-File looking something like this.
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": "112940",
            "Type": "type1",
            "Count": 11
        },
        {
            "ID": "1346",
            "Type": "type2",
            "Count": 156
        },
        {
            "ID": "7865",
            "Type": "type7",
            "Count": 23987
        }
    ]
}

It is located on a Zabbix Agent.
It gets update frequently by a cronjob to get the latest data.
The amount of objects changes.
Each Object should become one item in Zabbix.
Do I need to use code, or can I just do some configuration in the Zabbix-UI to get it to work ?
